# create javascript code for json multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have object values in an array. I want to create a JSON structure like the below. I have posted HTML and JS below but I do not know how to write javascript to create this JSON structure. Please help me anyone. Can you correct my javascript code?

```
{
    "family1": [{
        "checkedboxvalue": "test1"
    }, {
        "checkedboxvalue": "test2"
    }, {
        "checkedboxvalue": "test3"
    }],
    "family2": [{
        "checkedboxvalue": "test5"
    }, {
        "checkedboxvalue": "test6"
    }, {
        "checkedboxvalue": "test7"
    }],
    "family3": [{
        "checkedboxvalue": "test9"
    }, {
        "checkedboxvalue": "test10"
    }, {
        "checkedboxvalue": "test11"
    }]
}
```

```html
<div class="family1">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test1"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test2"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test3"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test4"/> 
</div>
<div class="family2">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test5"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test6"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test7"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test8"/> 
</div>
<div class="family3">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test9"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test10"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test11"/>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="test12"/> 
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript. This is not working properly. Can you find out that mistake?

```
var CollectionArray = []; 
var objects = ['family1', 'family2', 'family3'];
for (var i = 0; i <= objects.length; i++) {
    var familyObject = objects[i]; 
    var checkedboxvalue = ""; 
    $('.' + familyObject + ' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            checkedboxvalue = $(this).val(); 
            CollectionArray.push({
                familyObject: {
                    "checkedboxvalue": checkedboxvalue
                }
            });
        }
    });
    console.log(CollectionArray);
}
```

Comment: See the developer console of the browser. You will find Errors. Please post that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try someting like this

```
var CollectionArray = {};

var objects = [ 'family1' , 'family2' , 'family3' ];

var familyObject;

for ( var i = 0 ; i < objects.length ; i++ ) {
    familyObject = objects[i];
    $( '.' + familyObject + ' input[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).each( function () {
        !CollectionArray[ familyObject ] && ( CollectionArray[ familyObject ] = [] );
        CollectionArray[ familyObject ].push( this.value );
    } );

}

// CollectionArray.family1 is an array
```

Comment: that is not working. i am getting in developer console like this: Object {}

Comment: try to check a input before start the function.